# Mental Health and Planning

Tags: united-kingdom

There is a 2m height restriction on border fences in the UK.

Can the council allow that planning restriction to be circumvented if the perpetrator is claiming to have mental health problems? Can they allow this if those actions are having a detrimental effect on the lives of the victims?

Comment: If you're unhappy with a council planning decision, you should look at the council's complaints procedures. In extreme cases you may be able to launch a legal action: speak to a good solicitor. You could also consider suing your neighbour, or council services for resolving disputes between neighbours.

Answer (score 2):

### Enforcement of the law is discretionary

The police, or council, or any other administrative authority can decide if they will enforce the law on a case by case basis. They are entitled to consider the mental state of the alleged perpetrator. They can also consider the victims. They do not have to justify their discretion.